# Reviews page slow to load

Tags: bug

The [superuser reviews page](https://superuser.com/review) is considerably slower to load than the other SE reviews pages I frequent.  In addition, I have seen this a few times in the last few days.

[image]

So, the question is: *Why is the SU reviews page special?*

Comment: I don't know the underlying code at all, but I'd guess that the reviews page is generated from a very different set of information and relies on different processes. Also, as it is only accessed by a small subset of the site visitors it is probably assigned fewer host resources, leaving the server's power for the main pages. But, that's just a guess.